# Swift: Dependency Injection error with SceneDelegate

Tags: swift, dependency-injection

I'm trying to convert my APIManager from using singleton into dependency injection. But I'm constantly hitting the fatalError for the ViewController's initializer. Can anyone help and explain what's the problem? I put a break point in sceneDelegate and that isn't being called first. It's constantly calling the requiredInit from ViewController. Why is this happening? Also, I'm building out my UI programmatically.

```
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?


func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    
    if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
        let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
        
        let apiManager = APIManager()
        let vc = ViewController(apiManager: apiManager)
        window.rootViewController = vc
        
        self.window = window
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
    
    guard let _ = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
  }
}

class APIManager {
 enum Result<Value> {
    case success(Value)
    case failure(Error)
  }
}


class ViewController: UIViewController {

let apiManager: APIManager

init(apiManager: APIManager) {
    self.apiManager = apiManager
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
  
}
```

Error

```
Fatal error: init(coder:) has not been implemented: file RetrieveJSON/ViewController.swift, line 25
2020-09-24 11:06:06.124472-0400 RetrieveJSON[67925:3183237] Fatal error: init(coder:) has not been implemented: file RetrieveJSON/ViewController.swift, line 25
```

[image]

Comment: Use NSStoryboard to create the view controller and then set the apiManager property manually

Comment: What if I'm building out my UI programmatically

Comment: Then why is init(coder:) being called?

Comment: It something that I was forced to add because init(apiManager) required it. IDK why its being called. I'm setting my breakpoint in sceneDelegate where if statement is, but that block of code never gets called. Each time I run my app, I automatically hit the fatalError

Comment: Please show the **STACK TRACE** from the crash.  It sounds as if a storyboard or xib is being used without you expecting it.

Comment: Ok, thanks Phillip. Just edited my original post

Comment: From that portion of the trace, it definitely looks as if it is loading your view controller from a storyboard/xib file.  I suggest reviewing however you've tried to prevent that.